# WPF Document Viewer don't show data

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I have a problem with my Document Viewer in WPF. 
The Document  console.xps isn't showing up in the Viewer. Also in the Debugger the File isn't loading and goes into the catch-exception.

```
        try
        {

            windowconsole.Show();

            XpsDocument xps = new XpsDocument(@"C:\Users\console.xps", FileAccess.Read);

            windowconsole.doctxt.Document = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            xps.Close();

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Textfile don't open.");

        }
```

Would be great if someone could help me :)

Greetings
Blackbear

**Edit 29.01.19:** I get the Error Message: "*System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains damaged data.*" in the line *XpsDocument xps = new XpsDocument(path)*;

If i recreate the textfile, theres still the same Error Message, also if i change the .xps to .txt;

**Edit 31.01.2019:** Solved my problem with a ScrollViewer for the moment and will have a look at the Document Viewer later, if i'll find a solution, I will post it here. Also feel free to share your solution, if you have one. Also Thanks for your help <3 Helped me a lot.

Comment: The information about Exception type would be really helpful

Comment: "System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains damaged data." -> already created a new File, still isn't working.; Via Streamreader (showing in a Textbox), the file is working

Comment: Are you getting exception on `new XpsDocument()` line or next line?,

Comment: You should add relevant new information to your question where it is more visisble than in a comment.

Comment: @KlausGütter  Ok done :)

Comment: Did you consider that the error message is correct and the file is indeed damaged? Can it be opened in [XPS Viewer](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-XPS-Files)? If it is damaged: how do you create the XPS file?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, you are right. Seems like the file is damaged (didn't try open it in XPS Viewer to be honest - just in NotePad or other Textviewing tools where everything is correct and working). I am creating the file with the command " > console.xps", so I get the console output in a text document.

Comment: XPS is an XML-based format, you cannot use just any text output for it.

Comment: @KlausGütter Ok thank you :) Solved my problem with a ScrollViewer Box for now, but will take a look at the Document Viewer if I have some time left.